# Notification cannot be cleared after setOngoing(false)

Tags: android, service, notifications, audio-player, android-music-player

I have a music player which shows a media notification while audio is playing. I want the user to be able to dismiss the notification when music is paused.

I have to use startForeground so that the service will continue running AND it will stay attached to the activity. I've tried using a notification channel, once I kill the activity playback stops as well which isn't what I want (the code is still in there, commented out).

When the notification is shown, I call startForeground. setOngoing is set to playbackState == STATE_PLAYING. I call stopForeground when the service is destroyed or when playbackState == null || STOPPED.

Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/FNTSSzjS

Code snippet (because you need to include code with pastebin)

```
private void addPlayPauseAction(NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {
    String label;
    int icon;
    PendingIntent intent;
    if (playbackState.getState() == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING) {
        label = service.getString(R.string.play_pause);
        icon = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;
        intent = intentPause;
        builder.setOngoing(true);
    } else {
        label = service.getString(R.string.play_pause);
        icon = android.R.drawable.ic_media_play;
        intent = intentPlay;
        builder.setOngoing(false);
    }
    builder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(icon, label, intent));
}
```

relevant methods in PasteBin are **startNotification, stopNotification, createNotification, addPlayPauseAction, and setNotificationPlaybackState**

Answer (score 4):

Use `stopForeground(false)` and rebuild notification. You don't have to use `setOngoing` while using foreground service. For more information refer to this [page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

and search for `Running a service in the foreground`.